# Do you need external caching for a Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, performance, cache, query-cache, postgresql-performance

I am currently building a server and have just written a database connection using JDBC, Jooq, and added a DAO layer, which also handles transaction management.  I remember that databases can cache data when it queries.

I want to know if Postgres already handles this case or would I need to build anything on top (like the DAO layer) to handle caching?

Which third party tools would you recommend if so?

Comment: Why do you think you need external caching? Do you have performance problems? Do you anticipate them, and if so, why?

Comment: I just want to know if it is common for server side to use external caching for db.  Like the dao layer, its not necessary but good to have for future changes.